# HTTPS Redirected too many times after installing Letsencrypt in Apache2 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache2, httpd.conf, http-redirect, lets-encrypt

After installing lets encrypt it created it apache2-le-ssl.conf file and added the following code to it.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

and added following to apache2.conf

```
# HTTPS Redirect
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

This is how my app/ .htaccess file looks

```
# Uncomment the following to prevent the httpoxy vulnerability
# See: https://httpoxy.org/
#<IfModule mod_headers.c>
#    RequestHeader unset Proxy
#</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

and this is how my app/webroot/ .htaccess looks

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am getting an error of being redirected too many times. 
How can I resolve it without setting up anew.

Comment: I realized the existence of another apache2-le-ssl.conf in apache2/sites-enabled. I deleted the file. After which I was still getting 
an error but that of  "Err_ssl_protocol_error" : Site cannot provide a secure connection. At which I deleted the apache2/ apache2-le-ssl.conf as well and added the code from this file to my sites-enabled/000-default.conf file. I am now again getting a redirected too many times error.